"Code language not supported or defined" while trying to run Fortran 77 code with .f file

this is the right bottom corner of my VS code, I try to install fortran compiler according to this video, here I install code runner, C/C++ extensions and modern fortran for my code, then I want to run this project , after I download this, I use VS code to open the src folder, but when I click hyplas.f and click "run" button, it says that "Code language not supported or defined" , I don't know what to do, I'm using windows 10
it seems that I may need to add some .json files according to my experience with C++, but I don't know how to do this, I can't find any related tutorials, this is the sceenshot of my screen 

Use [fortran] for all Fortran questions. Follow the instructions displayed in the short descriptions of the tags you are adding.
